# Good Alternatives to Blat

Tags: email, log-files

We use Blat on one of our servers to email log files and reports nightly.  As the number of reports have increased it seems that Blat has been choking and outputting more and more errors.  Does anyone else use Blat or a good, small altern to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try [**bmail**](http://www.beyondlogic.org/solutions/cmdlinemail/cmdlinemail.htm), a free, lean command line SMTP mail sender for Win32 platforms. With the also free available utility *mpack* you can use bmail to send mime attachments.

Usage and options:

```
Usage: bmail [options]
       -s    SMTP Server Name
       -p    SMTP Port Number (optional, defaults to 25)
       -t    To: Address
       -f    From: Address
       -b    Text Body of Message (optional)
       -h    Generate Headers
       -a    Subject (optional)
       -m    Filename (optional) Use file as Body of Message
       -c    Prefix above file with CR/LF to separate body from header
       -d    Debug (Show all mail server communications)
```

**Update:**

Another alternative is **cmdsendmail**, one of the "[CommandLine Tools](http://www.stum.de/cmdtools/)" (open source, [hosted on CodePlex.com](http://cmdtools.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=27185)):

> cmdsendmail is a tool that allows to
>   send e-Mail from your Command Line. It
>   reads it’s settings from an Xml file,
>   which means you can easily use it in a
>   Batch File. For example, include it in
>   your Backup scripts (or any other
>   scheduled task) and have the script
>   send an e-Mail to you whenever the
>   backup task is finished, with the
>   neccessary Logfiles attached.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CMAIL as an alternative. It supports SSL/TLS which is nice.

https://inveigle.net/cmail/about.shtml